# connection between the same software installed on two computers like superbeam using c#

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, lan

I am developing a software using c#.net for file transfer between computers and laptops. And i am using IIS hosting. In superbeam for pc they ask for network interface on which receiver is connected and they are using one string if we enter that string in another machine then we can able to receive data. SO my question is how can i make connection like this between two pcs? or is there any other way? thank you.

Comment: Your users are all going to install IIS to run your thing..?

Comment: yes it should be enable but it will be automatically get enabled. my main problem is about such kind of connection between my application which will be installed on different computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the next time try to make question more clearly by reading wikis and making some researches on google anyway , from what I understood , you want to make a connection between two PCs so you need to know how to work with sockets with C# by knowing how does protocols work (TCP/IP in your case) then you have to know how to open a port in your firewall to give your application the rights to do that so after all of that the answer for the string that you've talked about it could be an IP address mixed with the opened port and they are encrypted ... many possibilities :) :)

Comment: Thank u so much sir.... i will look to it now.... Do u have some example for that?

Comment: in my opinion Delphi will be better for you but no problem look here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155282/TCP-Server-Client-Communication-Implementation , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ty sir i wil look to it n wil ask u if i hv any queries.

Comment: OK :) under your order sir :) :)